# Write a YARN application for a Non-JVM application

Tags: hadoop-yarn

Assume I want to use yarn cluster to run a Non-JVM distributed application (e.g. .Net based. is this a good idea?). From what I have read so far, I need to develop a [YARN application](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html) that consists of

- a YARN client that is used to submit the job to the yarn framework
- a YARN ApplicationMaster, which is the core to orchestra the application in the cluster.

It seems that the two pieces need to be written using Yarn APIs, which are offered as Jar libraries. It means they have to be written using one of the JVM languages. It seems it's possible to write the YARN client with REST APIs, correct? If yes, it means the client can be written with any language (e.g. C# on .Net).  However, for application master, this does not seem to be the case, and it has to use JVM. Correct?

I'm new to YARN. Just want to confirm whether my understanding is correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

The YARN Client and AppMaster need to be written in Java as they are the ones that write to the YARN Java API.  The RESTful API, https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html, is really about offering up the commands that you can do from the CLI.

Fortunately, your "container" processes can be just created with just about anything.  http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hadoop-yarn-concepts-and-applications/ says it best with the following quote:

"This allows the ApplicationMaster to work with the NodeManager to launch containers ranging from simple shell scripts to C/Java/Python processes on Unix/Windows to full-fledged virtual machines (e.g. KVMs)."

That said, if you are trying to bring a non-Java application (or even a Java one!) that is already a distributed application of sorts then the Slider framework, http://slider.incubator.apache.org/, is probably the best starting point for you.